# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, jpql

```java
session = sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier(jndiName).openSession();
String queryString = "SELECT acm FROM Appointment ap JOIN AppointmentCouponMapping acm on acm.appointmentCouponMappingId = ap.appointmentCouponMappingId WHERE ap.appointmentId = :appointmentId and ap.organizationId = :organizationId";
return (AppointmentCouponMapping) session.createQuery(queryString)
    .setLong("appointmentId", appointmentId)
    .setLong("organizationId", organizationId)
    .uniqueResult();
```

Error:

```
21:42:39,689 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
21:42:39,689 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3)  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'acm' {originalText=acm}
21:42:39,689 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3)
```

Comment: Please show the `Appointment` and `AppointmentCouponMapping` entities.

Comment: {@NotAudited
 @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_coupon_mapping_id", referencedColumnName = "appointment_coupon_mapping_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
 private AppointmentCouponMapping appointmentCouponMapping;}

Comment: @OneToOne  mapping

Comment: Are you sure the your mapping `@OneToOne` works at all? As well as I know there is a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263922/hibernate-onetoone-by-alternative-key) with `@OneToOne` mapping by not primary key column.